# Profiling cakephp find operations

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm looking to optimize my SQL queries for a growing website based on CakePHP. I can optimize things using recursive = -1, for example, but before going further, I think it'd be helpful to know which queries are taking the most time.

Is there a simple way to log the time queries are taking on a production site? The idea of adding code around each find() makes me want to quit before I start, and it doesn't look like the beforeFind and afterFind functions carry enough information to track which "after" corresponds to which "before".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the Debug Kit plugin for CakePHP or use the logging of your DB server? MySQL can be configured to even just log slow queries.

- https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit
- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html